# Return Image URL from firebase upload String Method

Tags: java, android, firebase

Hello I am trying to retrieve the Image URL from Firebase storage after image upload and display it in a Toast from the Image Upload method which would return the URL as a string.

I am able to get the URL but my toast runs before the image upload is complete hence returning an empty string response in place of the URL.

What i want to achieve is to get the image URL and then display it in the toast outside the Upload method if the upload is successful

This is what i have tried;

```
      insertImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(TestFirebaseImageUpload.this,  firebaseImageUpload(filePath), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

when the insertImage button is clicked it displays a toast which should contain the URL of the image which is gotten by sending the file uri to the firebaseImageUploadMethod.

This is my firebaseImage upload Method

```
    public String firebaseImageUpload(Uri filePath) {
        if (filePath != null) {
            // Setting progressDialog Title.
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setTitle(" Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            ref = imagePath.child("images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            ref.putFile(filePath)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(TestFirebaseImageUpload.this, "Uploaded ... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    URL = uri.toString();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            URL = "";
                            Toast.makeText(TestFirebaseImageUpload.this, "Not Uploaded ... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int) progress + "%");
                        }
                    });
        }
        return URL;
    }
```

What i want is to display the URL in the toast which is displayed when the insertImage Button is clicked.

Thanks

Comment: How do i do that please? and where is this bug

Comment: where you define `filePath` ? `Toast.makeText(TestFirebaseImageUpload.this,  firebaseImageUpload(filePath), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: I dont understand what im doing wrong please

Comment: You don't understand where you define `filePath` ?

Comment: Show us your retrieve image code.

Comment: You may want to move the toast inside ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    URL = uri.toString();                                                              
                               // Toast goes here                                                            }
                            });

Comment: the file path is a Uri. if i put the toast inside my onSuccess method  inside the onSuccess listener i get the URL in a toast message but i want to receive the URL outside the upload method  inside the toast in my onClick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a callback

```
onClick(){
      firebaseImageUpload(filePath, Callback)
    }

    onUploaded(){
      // Display toast here
    }

ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
    URL = uri.toString(); 
    callback.onUploaded(URL);
    }
    });

     interface Callback{
       void onUploaded(String url)
     }
```